# Based on the return value do Update/Insert statment

Tags: sql-server

I wonder if I can get a help with somehting,in SQL I Have 2 Tables the relation between them based on the Person ID and I want to write sp that checking if the person is already exit than:
do an insert into statement else do an update statement.

The Table that I'm checking if the value IsExit name :GSACPeopleBadgeRequest

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateIDBadgeInfo] 
     @PersonID Int,
     @RequestedBy Int,
     @RequestedOn SmallDatetime,
     @BadgeStatusType Int,
     @ShippedLocationID Int,
     @Notes Varchar(500)= NULL,
     @Active bit
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @retVal INT
SET @retVal = 0

DECLARE @CheckVal Bit
SET @CheckVal = 0


 IF @PersonID > 0
      BEGIN
        '#####################################How do this right.###########################
        @CheckVal  = select * from GSACPeopleBadgeRequest   where PersonID = @PersonID


    -- Check if there is any personID in GSACPeopleRequest, if not make a new insert
else
            Update  dbo.GSACPeopleBadgeRequest  
                 SET
                 RequestedBy = @RequestedBy,
                 RequestedOn = @RequestedOn,
                 BadgeStatusType = @BadgeStatusType,
                 ShippedLocationID = @ShippedLocationID ,
                 Notes = ISNULL(@Notes,@Notes),
                 Active = @Active
           WHERE PersonID = @PersonID

            -- Set the return value 
           SET @retVal = CAST(@@ROWCOUNT As int)

Select @retVal

END

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want do an insert when @personid is not found else if exists then update but in your question it is explained in opposite way. Try this.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   GSACPeopleBadgeRequest
               WHERE  PersonID = @PersonID)
  INSERT INTO GSACPeopleBadgeRequest
              (RequestedBy,RequestedOn,BadgeStatusType,ShippedLocationID,Notes,Active)
  SELECT @RequestedBy,
         @RequestedOn,
         @BadgeStatusType,
         @ShippedLocationID,
         Isnull(@Notes, ''),
         @Active
ELSE
  UPDATE dbo.GSACPeopleBadgeRequest
  SET    RequestedBy = @RequestedBy,
         RequestedOn = @RequestedOn,
         BadgeStatusType = @BadgeStatusType,
         ShippedLocationID = @ShippedLocationID,
         Notes = Isnull(@Notes, ''),
         Active = @Active
  WHERE  PersonID = @PersonID

-- Set the return value 
SET @retVal = Cast(@@ROWCOUNT AS INT)
```